# Having venv made with powershell 5, can I safely move/upgrade my shell to powershell 7?

Tags: django, powershell, python-venv

I have a **Django** project with `venv` made with **PowerShell 5.** I wonder if is it safe to install and use this project with **PowerShell 7**. If I would invoke my `venv` with a later version of **PowerShell** *(v7)*, will it cause some sort of a conflict, create bugs, or clashes?

Are there any data fetched by `venv` (and stored) related to **PowerShell?**

Comment: No, vitualenv doesn't depend on any specific PowerShell version, and activating an environment using a different version of PowerShell should work just fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that as *Mathias R. Jessen* said, this works as I have tested it myself. I didn't find any problems using **PowerShell 7** instead of **PowerShell 5** having the same **venv** I have had with **PowerShell 5**.

There is, also doable to add **PowerShell 7** to **Windows Terminal Preview.**